# Connecting points in ggplot2 graph with lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing

So as said in the question I want to connect points in ggplot2 graph. The points should be connected one after another in the order they are plotted to the graph, like this :

[image]
Sorry for the bad drawing.

```r
basepop <- matrix(c(10,30),nrow = 2)
matrixA <- matrix(c(0.4,-0.325,0.3,1.2),nrow = 2)
matrixA
z <- eigen(matrixA)
z$val
eigenmatrix <- z$vec
eigenmatrix
eigeninverse <- solve(eigenmatrix)
constmatrix <- eigeninverse %*% basepop
constmatrix



popdata = NULL

for(k in 1:100){
  predator <- c(constmatrix[1,1]*z$val[1]^k*z$vec[1,1] + constmatrix[2,1]*z$val[2]^k*z$vec[1,2])
  prey <- c(constmatrix[1,1]*z$val[1]^k*z$vec[2,1] + constmatrix[2,1]*z$val[2]^k*z$vec[2,2])
  
  popdata = rbind(popdata, data.frame(k,predator,prey))
}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(popdata, aes(predator, prey, color = k)) +
  geom_point()

ggplot(popdata, aes(k, predator, color = k)) +
  geom_point() 

ggplot(popdata, aes(k, prey, color = k)) +
  geom_point()
print(popdata)
```

This is my code for calculating the pop of a prey and predator system.

Comment: At `geom_line()` at the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Duck's comment: just add `+ geom_line()` or `+ geom_path()` to a plot. ("Which to use" depends on your use: `geom_line` connects by the order on the x-axis, `geom_path` connects in the order they appear in the data, both have valid uses. In *this* case they appear to be the same, but keep this in mind if your real data changes.)

```r
ggplot(popdata, aes(predator, prey, color = k)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot2 with connected lines]

(Similarly for the other plots.)

I should note that order matters.

```r
# left
ggplot(popdata, aes(predator, prey, color = k)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(color="black")
# right
ggplot(popdata, aes(predator, prey, color = k)) +
  geom_line(color="black") +
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2, side-by-side, point-over-line and reverse]